# Python IOError exception when creating a long file

Tags: python, filenames, ioerror

I get an IOError shown below when trying to open a new file using "open (fname, 'w+')". The complete error message is below.

The file does not exist, but I verified using "os.access(dir_name, os.W_OK)" and "os.path.exists (dir_name)" that the parent directory for the file does exist.

I am wondering if the file name is just too long for Windows, or if I am doing something wrong. Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Error message:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\op_models\Corp_Network_Nov12\abcde_corporate_nov_12.project\abcde_corporate_nov_12-ctr.rptd.dir\ctr\Non
>   Business Hours for
>   Weeknights\hourly_data_for_2_weeks\1294897740\json.data\Link\0\Link
>   Utilization\analyzer393146160-data0.js'

Comment: Thank you. The limit does go over 260 characters. The MSDN article mentions that we can use "\\?\" prefix for long file name, just curious if anyone knows how I can add the prefix to the file name. When I try to do a simple "+" operation, I get an error EOL while scanning single-quoted string'. (fname = '\\?\' + fname)

Comment: Use "\\\\?\\". A raw string won't work in this case.

Comment: Use forward slashes instead. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I tried using the "\\\\?\\" and "\\\\UNC\\?\\" by appending them to the file name and got the same exception. Any which way, when I try to create a file in windows explorer, it would not let me create the file (windows blocks me from adding characters). I guess this is a system limitation?

Answer (score 7):

In the Windows API the maximum path length is limited to 260 characters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Update: prepend "\\?\" to the path.

Comment: ... combined with the very confusing error value; it should be ENAMETOOLONG, not ENOENT.  I think this is one of those obscure Windows bugs that everyone is confused by at least once at some point in their career.

Comment: What about non-english languages? I feel that the maximum is lower.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some related code which works for me (I have very long file names and paths):

```
for d in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    dirname = d[0]
    files = d[2]
    for f in files:
        long_fname = u"\\\\?\\" + os.getcwd() + u"\\" + dirname + u"\\" + f
        if op.isdir(long_fname):
            continue
        fin = open(long_fname, 'rb')
        ...
```

Note that for me it only worked with a combination of all of the following:

1. Prepend '\\?\' at the front.
2. Use full path, not relative path.
3. Use only backslashes.
4. In Python, the filename string must be a unicode string, for example u"abc", not "abc".

Also note, for some reason `os.walk(..)` returned some of the directories as files, so above I check for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning that the Python string must be a Unicode string - that saved me!

Comment: The `os.getcwd()` fixed it for me. Has to be the whole path, not just a relative path.

Answer (score 4):

You can monkey patch the tarfile module with this:

```
import tarfile

def monkey_patch_tarfile():
    import os
    import sys
    if sys.platform not in ['cygwin', 'win32']:
        return
    def long_open(name, *args, **kwargs):
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath
        if len(name) >= 200:
            if not os.path.isabs(name):
                name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), name)
            name = "\\\\?\\" + os.path.normpath(name)
        return long_open.bltn_open(name, *args, **kwargs)
    long_open.bltn_open = tarfile.bltn_open
    tarfile.bltn_open = long_open

monkey_patch_tarfile()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the length of the filename, it's the contents of the filename...

Python is treating '\12' as a control sequence.

```
>>> fn='C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\op_models\Corp_Network_Nov12\abcde_corporate_nov_12.project\abcde_corporate_nov_12-ctr.rptd.dir\ctr\Non Business Hours for Weeknights\hourly_data_for_2_weeks\1294897740\json.data\Link\0\Link Utilization\analyzer393146160-data0.js'
>>> print fn
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\op_models\Corp_Network_Nov12bcde_corporate_nov_12.projectbcde_corporate_nov_12-ctr.rptd.dir\ctr\Non Business Hours for Weeknights\hourly_data_for_2_weeks
94897740\json.data\Link\Link Utilizationnalyzer393146160-data0.js
```

Using [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=raw#strings) for Windows filenames will help:

```
>>> fn=r'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\op_models\Corp_Network_Nov12\abcde_corporate_nov_12.project\abcde_corporate_nov_12-ctr.rptd.dir\ctr\Non Business Hours for Weeknights\hourly_data_for_2_weeks\1294897740\json.data\Link\0\Link Utilization\analyzer393146160-data0.js'
>>> print fn
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\op_models\Corp_Network_Nov12\abcde_corporate_nov_12.project\abcde_corporate_nov_12-ctr.rptd.dir\ctr\Non Business Hours for Weeknights\hourly_data_for_2_weeks\1294897740\json.data\Link\0\Link Utilization\analyzer393146160-data0.js
```

**Update**

Alternatively, use forward slashes '/' instead of backslashes '\', since these will work on all operating systems and will save you hassles with backslashes right at the end of a pathname as in your comments.

See also [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) .

**Update 2**

Simplified demonstration of problem:

```
>>> open('.\12\n\r\file.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\n\n\r\x0cile.txt'
>>> open('./12/n/r/file.txt')
<open file './12/n/r/file.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7ff83f98>

C:\Users\johnysweb>copy .\12\n\r\file.txt con
Blah
        1 file(s) copied.
```

Comment: You're better off consistently using forward slashes; they work fine in Windows and it results in code that's much more likely to work on other platforms.

Comment: The OP used a correctly encoded file path. Otherwise the error message would have been different (TypeError).

Comment: @cgohlke: Please see my second update which demonstrates the `IOError` exception with the same text as the OP reported.

Comment: I do think the encoding is correct, since I just tried a different file name (sm.txt with the whole path) that keeps me within the 260 character limit, and that did work without an exception. I do see the file being created.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I don't doubt that one can get an IOError using incorrectly encoded path names. However, the path name used by the OP contains a NULL byte "\0" and this will lead to a TypeError in the open function. It is also unlikely that the 260+ character path name was typed manually by the OP. More likely it was the result of a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the entire path and then append the necessary Windows long path format. It should be noted that this doesn't work for accessing data from remote directories i.e. paths that begin with '\\some_remote_location\..' so you will need to map that directory locally in order to get "long path" to work.

```
if len(path_and_file) > 250: #I think the max is 260 but I left a buffer :)
    path_and_file = '\\\\?\\'+path_and_file
```